# Class for A = K * B in MATLAB (non-dependent properties with dependent behavior)

Tags: matlab, class, oop, set

I want to implement a class for the function A = K * B, where all properties are non-dependent. However, I would like to change a property dynamically when one of the other properties changes.

I have started from a very simple class and ended up with the following. Is there an easier or more strong way (e.g. software pattern, use special set/get approaches etc..) to do this in MATLAB? (MATLAB gives lots of warnings in the setter functions)

```
classdef AeqKxB
    properties
        A
        B
        K
        Kstate
    end

    properties (Access = private)
        i   %  i=0 during construnction, i=1 normal operation
        ia  %  ia = 1 to trick the setter function of B
        ib  %  ib = 1 to trick the setter function of A
    end

    methods

        function obj = MyClass2(a, k, kstate)  %   Constructor
            obj.i = 0;  %  Construction starts
            obj.A = a;
            obj.B = obj.A*k;
            obj.K = k;
            obj.Kstate = kstate;

            obj.i = 1;  %  Construction complete, ready for normal operation
            obj.ia = 0; %  Do not trick Set.B function for now
            obj.ib = 0; %  Do not trick Set.A function for now
        end

        function obj = set.A(obj, a) %   setter for A
            if obj.i == 0 %  During construnction use normal operation
                obj.A = a;
            elseif obj.i == 1 %  After construction

                if obj.ia == 0 && obj.ib == 0
                    obj.A = a;
                    obj.ia = 1;               %  Get ready to Trick Set.B function
                    obj.B = obj.A / obj.K;
                    obj.ia = 0;               %  Trick finished, return to original
                elseif obj.ia == 0 && obj.ib == 1
                    %  Tricked Set.A function
                    obj.A = a;
                end

            end
        end

        function obj = set.B(obj, b) %  setter for B
            if obj.i == 0 %  During construnction use normal operation
                obj.B = b;
            elseif obj.i == 1 %  After construction

                if obj.ia == 0 && obj.ib == 0;
                    obj.B = b;
                    obj.ib = 1;               %  Get ready to Trick Set.A function
                    obj.A = obj.B * obj.K;
                    obj.ib = 0;               %  Trick finished, return to original
                elseif obj.ia == 1 && obj.ib == 0;
                    %  Tricked Set.B function
                    obj.B = b;
                end

            end
        end

        function obj = set.K(obj,k) %  setter for K
            if obj.i == 0
                obj.K = k;
            elseif obj.i == 1
                if strcmp(obj.Kstate, 'FixB')
                    obj.K = k;
                    obj.A = obj.B * obj.K;
                elseif strcmp(obj.Kstate, 'FixA')
                    obj.K = k;
                    obj.B = obj.A / obj.K;
                end
            end
        end

        function obj = set.Kstate(obj,kstate)
            obj.Kstate = kstate;
        end

    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/263117-class-for-a-k-b-in-matlab-non-dependent-properties-with-dependent-behavior). I post his response:

"where all properties are non-dependent" Why? Your properties are obviously dependent, so why not use them.

The warnings are telling you that if an object is saved in a mat file it may not be restored properly due to random initialisation order. In practice, with your design, that shouldn't be a problem as the properties' values should always be consistent, so I guess you could just disable the warnings.

However, I can't help but greatly dislike this design, particularly the i state variable. You could achieve a cleaner design, using dependent variables, with no impact on performance:

```
classdef AeqKxB
    properties(Dependent)
        A;
        B;
        K;
    end
    properties
        Kstate;
    end
      properties (Access = private)
          A_;
          B_;
          K_;
      end
      methods
           function obj = AeqKxB(a, k, kstate)  %   Constructor
              obj.A_ = a;
              obj.B_ = a*k;
              obj.K_ = k;
              obj.Kstate = kstate;
          end
          function a = get.A(obj)
              a = obj.A_;
          end
          function obj = set.A(obj, a) %   setter for A
             obj.A_ = a;
             obj.B_ = a / obj.K_;
          end
          function b = get.B(obj)
              b = obj.B_;
          end
          function obj = set.B(obj, b) %  setter for B
              obj.B_ = b;
              obj.A_ = b * obj.K_;
          end
          function obj = set.K(obj,k) %  setter for K
              obj.K_ = k;
              if strcmp(obj.Kstate, 'FixB')
                  obj.A_ = obj.B_ * k;
              elseif strcmp(obj.Kstate, 'FixA')
                  obj.B_ = obj.A_ / k;
              end
          end
          function obj = set.Kstate(obj,kstate)
              obj.Kstate = kstate;
          end
      end
  end
```